# How to display a certain template element only for posts published within certain time range?

Tags: posts, comments, templates, facebook, date

I recently migrated a blog from sub.domain.com to blogs.domain.com/sub/. Because I'm using Facebook comments, all the posts published before April 25 need to reference sub.domain.com/blog-entry-title as the fb:comments href.

I know how to display certain posts for my date range with this code:

```
<?php
      function filter_where($where = '') {
      //posts for Jan 1 to April 26, 2012
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '2012-03-01' AND post_date <= '2012-03-15'";
    return $where;
      }
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
query_posts($query_string);
?>
```

But can I manipulate this code to use at the template level to say: "If post published before April 25, display xyz comments; else display abc comments."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do something like this in your template code:

```
<?php
    $migrate_date = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2012);
    if ( get_the_date('U') > date('U', $migrate_date) ) {
        echo "<p>New</p>\n";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Old</p>\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hmm, that sesms right but not quite working.

Comment: I added the code above to my template's single.php and tested on a few pages. It works.

Comment: Aha! I see what I did wrong; just needed to change the date. Thank you.